# python: reading in a table and converting each column to the right data type

Tags: python

Suppose I have a text file like with rows like below:

```
3, 4.32, hi
7, 3.23, hello
```

When I read in this file, all entries are treated as strings.  Is there a way for them to be automatically converted (in my example) to int, float, and string?

Comment: Do you know that the pattern is always `int`, `float`, `str`?  Or are you trying to have them automatically converted to whatever "makes sense"?

Comment: what do you mean by automatically ?

Comment: I mean that you can assume that each column will have the same "true" data type, but I want to do this for multiple text files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A primitive method:

```
def guess(text):
    for t in text.split(','):
        for typ in (int, float, str):
            try:
                yield typ(t)
                break
            except ValueError as e:
                pass

d = '3, 4.32, hi'

print list(guess(d))
# [3, 4.32, ' hi']
# [<type 'int'>, <type 'float'>, <type 'str'>]
```

However - if you know what the types should be, then that's much better than brute forcing like this...

And you could utilise the `ast` library to do some of the work, which will be potentially more flexible, require less hits on the try/except mechanism (and reads a bit easier, but does require a little bit of work on pre-processing the inputs)

```
def guess2(text):
    from ast import literal_eval
    tokens = (t.strip() for t in text.split(','))
    for token in tokens:
        try:
            token_value = literal_eval(token)
            token_type = type(token_value)
            yield token_value, token_type
        except ValueError as e:
            yield token, type(token)
```

Comment: So this basically works because an int conversion is more restrictive than a float conversion, which is more restrictive than a str conversion?

Comment: You've already got `str` (almost a no-op) - so that comes last... and a `float` will swallow an `int` so it goes before `float`... So, yeah basically. If you know the types they should be - that's a much better way of doing it, otherwise, generally you use this kind of ordering...

Comment: @qua I've also put an option in that uses `ast.literal_eval` which is potentially nicer

Comment: +1, because the `literal_eval` option is probably the best way to do it, and because of the comment about parsing the actual types instead of programmatically guessing.

Comment: @Jon Clements: thanks for the second answer.  What I actually want is to extract the data type from the entry, as opposed to converting it.  I can see how to modify your first answer for this, but is there something like literal_eval but to get the data type?

Comment: I guess i could do literal_eval(term) == int(term), etc.  Seems kind of clunky

Answer (score 1):

If you know the types in advance you can do this:

```
import csv
type_funcs = [int, float, str]
with open('yourfile.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        typed_row = [func(val) for func, val in zip(type_funcs, row)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another quickie if there is a fixed pattern in all the files.

```
def update_types():
    f = open("txtfile", "r")
    reader = f.readlines()
    for line in reader:
        parts = line.split(',')
        parts[0], parts[1] = int(parts[0]), float(parts[1])
        for part in parts:
            print type(part)
    f.close()
```